# How to execute a script on change-sets introduced by old commits?

Tags: git, git-rebase

How can I edit the **change-sets** introduced by a significant number of old commits in my repository. For example I want to change all appearances of "**foo**" with "**bar**" in all my files changed along several commits. Because there is a big number of commits, I don't want to do that manually. I know that "**git rebase -i**" has the option to "**exec**" ("x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell") but how can I specify the change-set on which I want the script to run?

Let's assume I have the history structure as shown bellow:

```
                    A---B---C---D.....---P---Q topic
                   /
           A'---B'---C' master
```

Many of the commits A, B, .... P and Q have introduced in the source files the word "**foo**". Now I want to change all those appearances of "**foo**" with "**bar**" but to also keep the history as it is now (i.e. have the separate commits as they are). How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Check out `git filter-branch`, in particular look it up in the excellent [git book](http://git-scm.com/book). The [git magic](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~blynn/gitmagic/) page is full of tips and tricks.